# Using VBA Runtime error 13 'type mismatch' while assigning a modified cell value back to the cell

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, type-mismatch

My code is below, the line that gives the error, type mismatch, runtime error 13 is the line within the for loop. WHy is this happening and how can I avoid it?

```
Workbooks(theFile).Worksheets(1).Columns("G:G").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "0.00"

For Each myCell In Columns("G:G")
    myCell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(WorksheetFunction.Clean(myCell.Value))
Next
```

Comment: mismatch usually means the data types don't match. Are you doing this on text or numbers?

Comment: Numbers. IS clean not usable on numbers, or trim????

Comment: `Clean()` and `Trim()` both work on numbers. Your number format is defined as "0.00" so any number that's not in that format will result in a mismatch error, I think

Comment: The numbers come from that cell though, so how would it be an issue??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably something like

```
For Each myCell In Columns("A:A").Cells
     myCell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(myCell.Value)
Next
```