# How adding ".Cells" solves run-time error 13?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

Can you please explain solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231343/using-vba-runtime-error-13-type-mismatch-while-assigning-a-modified-cell-value/53024618#53024618)?
I'm having the same problem but can't understand how adding ".Cells" solves the issue of run-time error 13 'type mismatch'?

Comment: Look at the definitions for what is returned by `Worksheet.Columns` vs `Range.Cells`.  They are different.  One returns a Range object consisting of a column (or columns).  The other returns a Range object consisting of the cells in that range object.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, please correct my understanding of what `Range` is. In my mind `Range` is a set of cells, no matter if defined by column, row or selection. I'd like to understand it properly not to be caught by this again. I took me some, ekhm, days before I posted a question... ;)

Comment: A Range object "represents a cell, a row, a column, a selection of cells containing one or more contiguous blocks of cells, or a 3-D range". So if your Range object happens to represent a column, and you want to loop through the cells comprising that column, you need to examine the cells property of the range object. I'll add some examples below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error 13 is caused by the mismatched argument which was passed to [Clean](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.clean?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm137136)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) function. This function expects `string` but here `array` is passed.

Why array? Because the `myCell.Value` is an array. `myCell` referes to whole column of cells in this case. HTH

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim myCell As Variant
    Dim myValue As Variant

    For Each myCell In Columns("G:G")
        Debug.Print TypeName(myCell) ' Range
        Debug.Print myCell.Address ' $G:$G
        Debug.Print myCell.Cells.Count ' e.g. 1048576

        myValue = myCell.Value
        Debug.Print TypeName(myValue) ' Variant()
        Debug.Print IsArray(myValue) ' True

        ' Here comes the type mismatch from
        ' It is because Clean accepts not an array, but a string
        WorksheetFunction.Clean (myCell.Value)

        ' It fails beause of mismatch argument typy which is passed to Clean function
        myCell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(WorksheetFunction.Clean(myCell.Value))
    Next
End Sub
```

So `Columns("G:G")` returns a `Range` of all cells in one column. The code could be written e.g. like this to show it.

```
Sub CellsOfColumn()
    Dim myColumn As Range
    Dim myCell As Range

    For Each myColumn In Columns("G:G")
        Debug.Print TypeName(myColumn) ' Range 
        Debug.Print myColumn.Address ' $G:$G
        Debug.Print myColumn.Cells.Count ' e.g. 1048576
        For Each myCell In myColumn.Cells
            Debug.Print TypeName(myCell) ' Range
            Debug.Print myCell.Address ' $G$1, $G$2, $G$3, $G$4 ...
            Debug.Print myCell.Cells.Count ' 1, 1, 1, 1, ...
            ' This now works because 
            ' myCell.Value is now a single value not an array,
            ' where myCell refers not to column, but to a single cell  
            myCell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(WorksheetFunction.Clean(myCell.Value))
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a good question.
  It is   because  `Columns` is a distinct Object *(with it's own properties and methods)* which are quite different than `Cells` *(which is the smallest unit of a `Range`)*.

In the Post you referenced, we want to loop over the `Cells` in a single column rather than the `Columns` in part of a worksheet.

Answer (score 2):

`Worksheet.Columns` (or `Worksheet.Columns(1)`) returns a range object that consists of the entire column(s).  If you want to loop through the individual cells of that column, you need to specify the `.Cells` property.

A **Range Object** *represents a cell, a row, a column, a selection of cells containing one or more contiguous blocks of cells, or a 3-D range"*.

So depending on what, exactly, is being returned, determines what is being looped through.

For example, here we create a range object which consists of three columns:

```
    Dim myRange As Range, myRangeObj As Range

Set myRange = Range(Columns(1), Columns(3))
For Each myRangeObj In myRange
    Debug.Print myRangeObj.Address
Next myRangeObj
```

The above will return:

```
$A:$A
$B:$B
$C:$C
```

But, if you change 'myRange' to refer to the individual cells:

```
 Set myRange = Range(Columns(1), Columns(3)).Cells
```

Then the above will return the address of each cell in each of the columns.

*Shortened output*

```
$A$1
$B$1
$C$1
$A$2
$B$2
$C$2
$A$3
$B$3
$C$3
$A$4
$B$4
$C$4
$A$5
$B$5
$C$5
$A$6
$B$6
$C$6
$A$7
$B$7
$C$7
$A$8
$B$8
$C$8
$A$9
$B$9
$C$9
$A$10
$B$10
$C$10
...
```